# Adding a new Vector Asset alters ids for existing Android resources?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

This has been happening off and on whether I'm using SVGs I downloaded from the material.io site or even if I'm using the "clipart" material icon SVGs that come bundled with Android Studio.

As an example, I go to File > New > Vector Asset, choose "Clip Art" and select the icon named "exposure plus 1". I accept the default values and it creates this xml file for me in my drawable directory: src/main/res/drawable/ic_baseline_exposure_plus_1_24.xml:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
  <path
      android:fillColor="#FF000000"
      android:pathData="M19,5v14H5V5h14m0,-2H5c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v14c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2V5c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2z"/>
</vector>
```

Just the act of adding this xml file seems to do something terrible to my R.txt generated file, though, so that id values are assigned wrong. Prior to adding this file, my app launches and images are displayed correctly.  After adding this file, when I clean and rebuild and relaunch my app, even without making any changes anywhere in the code, suddenly all the `ImageView`s are displaying the wrong images, so for example a tile that is populated with `R.drawable.somePng` is now displaying `R.drawable.otherPng`.

When I debug I can see that the code is still calling for R.drawable.somePng but that the id value that is populated actually corresponds to R.drawable.otherPng in the R.txt file.

Why would this be happening and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: "suddenly all the ImageViews are displaying the wrong images" -- where are the drawable resource IDs coming from that you are using? For example, did you try saving an `R.drawable` ID value in a file or database, and then are loading that value from the file/database and trying to apply it to an `ImageView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While typing a response to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware)'s comment, I think I've figured out the problem.

My app lets users create, save, and modify RPG characters.  There is a list of stock characters users can choose from and when these are created I save them in a data object similar to this:

```
class CharacterData {
  final String name;
  ... etc
  @DrawableRes
  final int mainImage;
}
```

The problem is when I add a new image it changes/reorders the allocated resource id hex values.  So when I load my app again, I load this saved character object with a saved resource id hex value that no longer points to the same file.

Seems like I'll need a new way to save/reference these images if I want to be able to continue adding onto the app without borking any previously saved characters.